# Downgrade Microsoft Office Pro 2013 to 2010 retail

Tags: microsoft-office, downgrade

I am still running SBS2003 on a VM network with WinXP and win 7 32&64 I purchased a office pro 2013 and I realize that it is not compatible with exchange 2003. Can I downgrade this to 2010 Pro or do I need to return it and find a 2010 pro on line?

Comment: In case it matters: "Outlook 2013 will work with Exchange 2003 using POP3 or IMAP." http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_home-outlook/outlook-2013-doesnt-support-exchange-2003-sp2/6e08e42e-f1a9-4f80-9b39-5120a955cdf2

Answer (score 1):

Office doesn't come with downgrade licensing, so you will need to purchase another copy, or upgrade your version of exchange, whichever you prefer.